# Complex Integration and trigonometric functions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am just begining with complex integration. Please help with this.
Evaluate $\int_{-i\pi}^{i\pi}\cos z dz$ where $z$ is a complex number.

This is my effort,
I know that $\int_{C}{f(z)dz} = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$ where C:[a,b] is a complex curve and $a \leq t \leq b$

Step one would be to determine z(t) from the path of integration and this is the toughest part for me.

Once I have obtaine z(t) I hope the rest would be easy

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: *Hint:* Does the result depend on the path of integration?

Comment: Martin R ofcourse it must

Comment: $z(t)=p+t(q-p)$ for $t\in [0,1]$. is a parametrisation of a line from $p$ to $q$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Let me try that z(t) = p + t(q - p) and see what I can get

Answer (score 1):

$f(z) = \cos(z)$ is the derivative of $F(z) = \sin(z)$. Therefore, for *any* path $C$ joining $a=-i\pi$ and $b= i\pi$ is
$$
\int_{C}{f(z)dz} = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt = \int_a^b \frac{d}{dt}(F(z(t)) \,  dt = F(b) - F(a) \\
= \sin(i\pi) - \sin(-i \pi) = 2 \sin(i\pi)\, .
$$

Generally, $\int_{C}{f(z)dz}$ depends only on the endpoints of $C$ if $C$ is a path in a simply-connected domain $D$ where $f$ is holomorphic, that is the contents of Cauchy's integral theorem.

Comment: I get the same answer if I follow the advice of Fakemistake(see comments). I see you have used chain rule for $\frac {dF(z(t))}{dt} = \frac{dF}{dz} × \frac{dz}{dt}$. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys just figured it out

From
$\int_{C} f(z)dz = \int_a^b f(z(t))z'(t)dt$

But
$z(t) = p + t(q - p)$ for $t \in [0,1]$

In our case
$p = -i\Pi$ and $q = i\Pi$

Then
$z(t) = -i\Pi + t(i\Pi + i\Pi)$
$z(t) = i\Pi (2t - 1)$
and
$z'(t) = 2i\Pi$

Also
$f(z(t)) = cos(i\Pi (2t - 1))$

Therefore

$\int_{-i\Pi}^{i\Pi} coszdz = \int_0^1 cos(i\Pi(2t - 1)) 2i\Pi dt$

$= 2i\Pi \int_0^1 cos(i\Pi(2t - 1)) dt$

Let $w = i\Pi(2t - 1)$

then
$dt = \frac{dw}{2i\Pi}$

$= \int_0^1 coswdw$
$= sinw$ from 0 to 1

$= sin(i\Pi(2t - 1))$ from 0 to 1
$= sin(i\Pi) - sin(-i\Pi)$

Therefore

$\int_{-i\Pi}^{i\Pi} coszdz = 2sin(i\Pi)$